# how can i have total cost of all items that been add by the user?

Tags: php

hi i want to ask on how can i have a total cost of an item. i have cart and it shows only price quantity and cost of each item. i want to have total of cost of all items that been add by the user please help

this is my cart code

```html
<?php 


//Start the session
session_start();

//Create 'cart' if it doesn't already exist
if (!isset($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'])){ $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] = array(); }


//Add an item only if we have the threee required pices of information: name, price, qty
if (isset($_GET['add']) && isset($_GET['price']) && isset($_GET['qty'])){
 //Adding an Item
 //Store it in a Array
 $ITEM = array(
  //Item name  
  'item_name' => $_GET['add'], 
  //Item Price
  'price' => $_GET['price'], 
  //Qty wanted of item
  'qty' => $_GET['qty']  
  );

 //Add this item to the shopping cart
 $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'][] =  $ITEM;
 //Clear the URL variables
 header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
//Allowing the modification of individual items no longer keeps this a simple shopping cart.
//We only support emptying and removing
else if (isset($_GET['remove'])){
 //Remove the item from the cart
 unset($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'][$_GET['remove']]);
 //Re-organize the cart
 //array_unshift ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'], array_shift ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART']));
 //Clear the URL variables
 header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

}
else if (isset($_GET['empty'])){
 //Clear Cart by destroying all the data in the session
 session_destroy();
 //Clear the URL variables
 header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

}
else if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
 //Updates Qty for all items
 foreach ($_POST['items_qty'] as $itemID => $qty) {
  //If the Qty is "0" remove it from the cart
  if ($qty == 0) {
   //Remove it from the cart
   unset($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'][$itemID]);
  }
  else if($qty >= 1) {
   //Update to the new Qty
   $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'][$itemID]['qty'] = $qty;
  }
 }
 //Clear the POST variables
 header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
} 

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title><?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?> Online Order Form</title>
<style>


#formArea #orderForm #formColumns {
 width:650px;
 margin:auto;
}
#formArea #orderForm #formColumns #leftColumn {
 float:left;
 width:300px;
}
#orderForm {
 height:500px;
}
#formArea #orderForm #formColumns #rightColumn {
 float:right;
 width:300px;
}
#formArea #orderForm #formColumns th {
 text-align: left;
}
.copyright {
 font-size: 9pt;
}






</head>

<body>
    
        <?php 
        //Print all the items in the shopping cart
        foreach ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] as $itemNumber => $item) {
        ?>
        <tr id="item<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>">    
            <td><a href="?remove=<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>">remove</a></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['item_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['price']; ?></td>
            <td><input name="items_qty[<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>]" type="text" id="item<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>_qty" value="<?php echo $item['qty']; ?>" size="2" maxlength="3" /></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['qty'] * $item['price']; ?></td>
        
   
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
 <?php $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART_HTML'] = ob_get_flush(); ?>
    <p>
      <label>
      <input type="submit" name="update" id="update" value="Update Cart" />
      </label>
    </p>
</form>
<p><a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Keep Shopping</a> - <a href="?empty">Empty</a> Cart</p>
</div>
<label>
     <form action="form.php">
    <input type="submit" id="checkout" value="Check Out" />
</form>
   
   
   
   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this fragment you can simply add something like `$total` variable:

```
<?php 
    //Print all the items in the shopping cart
    //## Declare your total value
    $total = 0;

    foreach ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] as $itemNumber => $item) {
        //## Count item price value
        $price_value = $item['qty'] * $item['price'];
        //## Sum prices:
        $total += $price_value;
    ?>
    <tr id="item<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>">    
        <td><a href="?remove=<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>">remove</a></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['item_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['price']; ?></td>
        <td><input name="items_qty[<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>]" type="text" id="item<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>_qty" value="<?php echo $item['qty']; ?>" size="2" maxlength="3" /></td>
        <td><?php echo $price_value ?></td><tr>
    <?php
    } 
    ?>
    <tr>
         <td colspan="4">Sum:</td>
         <td> <?php echo $total; //## echo your total ?> </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Nike\order.php on line 378

Comment: The error is in here foreach ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] as $itemNumber => $item)

Comment: should be $total = 0; I forgot about `;` sign

Comment: thanks gotcha it works

Comment: i will make another question again about those items saving to database is it possible? i didnt input all the items to database. i want to use insert only. what all i mean is for reservation only

Comment: Of course you can save those items to db. If you want to use plain PHP, you can use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php). If my answer about $total is proper please mark it as a accepted.